# Roblox Lua Script, It is possible to simulate a key being pressed?

Tags: input, lua, user-input, simulation, roblox

I'm making a game to play with my friends which uses others people scripts/mechanics
and in theses scripts has a key bind set to a specific key which is "Q" and one of my friends play on console which he can't do that action which is the main core of my game.

I've search it everywhere and nothing, I found about VirtualUser but it only works for command bar.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to simulate a key press.

However, you can bind the logic that is executed when the key is pressed to also fire with controller input as well. Take a look at the docs for [ContextActionService:BindAction](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/ContextActionService/BindAction).

The BindAction function accepts a few arguments :

- **actionName** : a string to uniquely identify the action
- **functionToBind** : a function that will get called when that action is dispatched
- **createTouchButton** : a boolean, when true will create a button on touch devices like phones and tablets
- **inputTypes** : a tuple of all of the different keys to listen for

So you can use this to bind multiple inputs, including controller input, to the same logic as what happens when you would press the letter `q`. For example ...

```
local ContextActionService = game:GetService("ContextActionService")

local function handleAction(actionName, inputState, inputObject)
    if actionName == "DoThing" then
        if inputState == Enum.UserInputState.Begin then
            print("Time to do the thing")
        end
    end
end
 
-- Do a thing when the user presses q or the Y Button on a controller
ContextActionService:BindAction("DoThing", handleAction, true, Enum.KeyCode.Q, Enum.KeyCode.ButtonY)
```

For more information, see...

- the list of all of the [KeyCode](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/enum/KeyCode)s
- the list of all [UserInputState](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/enum/UserInputState)s